# Get value of form text field with without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a form on my page and want to be able to submit the text box value (partnumber) as a query string in a hyperlink without submitting the form itself ? Is this possible ?
I have done some research and have tried document.getElementById("partnumber").value but am getting the error "Object Required". Code Below.

```
 <form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="formpost?rmaid=<%=rmaid%>">
    <input name="partnumber" type="text" id="partnumber" size="10" />
<a href="suggest.asp?partnumber=<%document.getElementById("partnumber").value%>"><span class="style11">Suggest Link</span></a>
<input name="invoice" type="text" id="invoice" size="15" />
</form>
```

I'll set the new page to open in a pop up window and list a series of values in the database but then I need the value selected to come back into the invoice field on the original page. I believe this can be done with JavaScript but I am new to this, can anyone help ?

***For those Looking to pass values back I have found this snippet that works...
Put this in the child window***

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function changeParent() { 
  window.opener.document.getElementById('Invoice').value="Value changed..";
  window.close();
} 
</script> 

<form> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:changeParent()" value="Change opener's textbox's value.."> 
</form>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to insert JS code in `<% .. %>` tag. But that's for ASP script, not for JS. JS code must be inside `<script>` tag

Comment: That doesn't work either <a href="suggest.asp?partnumber=<script>document.getElementById("partnumber").value</script>"> just passing text through, not whats in the actual textbox.

Comment: Also tried this - <script>
var scrt_var = document.getElementById("partnumber").value;
</script> in the header followed by <a href="suggest.asp" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?partnumber='+scrt_var;return false;">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the input field you should add an OnChange to it. This event should call a function which will then set your link's value.

You can see an example of this here (it uses a button press though and not an input OnChange Event): http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/ChangeURLandtextofahyperlink.htm

**Edit:** Added a Stack Snippet illustrating the solution.

```js
function SetSuggestLink() {
    var suggest = document.getElementById('partnumber').value;
    document.getElementById('innerSpan').innerHTML = 
        "Suggest Link: suggest.asp?partnumber=" + suggest;
    document.getElementById('QueryLink').href = 
        "suggest.asp?partnumber=" + suggest;
}
```

```css
.style11 {
  color:black;
}

.style2 {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="formpost?rmaid=SomeValue">
    <input name="partnumber" type="text" id="partnumber" size="10" 
           OnChange="SetSuggestLink()" /> </br>
    <a id="QueryLink" class="style2" href="#">
      <span id="innerSpan" class="style11">Suggest Link</span>
    </a></br>
    <input name="invoice" type="text" id="invoice" size="15" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks KHeaney, but how can I set it to be the value of whats currently in the part number text field ? I don't understand how to pass the link from the text field to a query string.

Comment: Thank You - This is perfect and I have managed to change it so it opens in a pop-up window.    document.getElementById('QueryLink').href = 
        "javascript:popUp3('suggest.asp?partnumber=" + suggest + "')";

Comment: Is there a way of passing a value back from the popup window to the original into the invoice text box ?

Comment: Its ok done it :) - thanks for your help !
    <script language="javascript"> 
    function changeParent() { 
      window.opener.document.getElementById('Invoice').value="Value changed..";
      window.close();
    } 
    </script> 

    <form> 
    <input type=button onclick="javascript:changeParent()" value="Change opener's textbox's value.."> 
    </form>